# How to apply if else condition for SikuliLibrary with RobotFramework?

Tags: robotframework, sikuli

I'm using SikuliLibrary with RobotFramework for automating windows desktop application. One case is like: sometimes you need to put login credentials sometimes not, So I have to apply if else condition for SikuliLibrary with RobotFramework? I mean if login screen appear then will put credentials otherwise not. as it is image based So, I'm unable to apply if else condition.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the login executed unconditionally, in a [`Run Keyword And Ignore Error`](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Ignore%20Error) block, and continue if it (the login) wasn't present:

```
${rc}  ${msg}    Run Keyword And Ignore Error     Do Sikuli Login
Run Keyword If     "${rc}" == 'FAIL' and "${msg}" != 'the expected message when the login was not present'
...    Fail    The Login keyword failed unexpectedly: ${msg}
```

Naturally, this would be useful only if the login must/may happen at certain points in your scenarios, not on semi-random basis (it's not clear to me isn't it the latter from your question).

*Disclaimer: I've never used RF with Sikuli, only each by itself - can be totally off the mark here.*