# How to apply If, Else condition in `RobotFramework` with `SikuliLibrary` by two image on RIDE?

Tags: if-statement, robotframework, sikuli

**Example:** After clicking on the app icon a login screen(`login_screen.png`) appear, Sometimes one OK pop up dialog(`ok_btn_dialog.png`) coming before the login screen, If the the OK dialog appear I want to click on the OK button (`ok_btn_dialog.png`) then continue with Login screen(`login_screen.png`) , otherwise it will continue from Login screen(`login_screen.png`).

How to apply If, Else condition in `RobotFramework` with `SikuliLibrary`? by using those two image on RIDE.

One answer here, but it's not exactly [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53543243/how-to-apply-if-else-condition-for-sikulilibrary-with-robotframework) of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an `Exists` [keyword](http://rainmanwy.github.io/robotframework-SikuliLibrary/doc/SikuliLibrary.html#Exists) that will tell you if an image exists on screen. [This results](https://github.com/rainmanwy/robotframework-SikuliLibrary/blob/master/src/java/com/github/rainmanwy/robotframework/sikulilib/keywords/ScreenKeywords.java#L832) in a true/false response that can be used by the `Run Keyword If` [keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If):

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SikuliLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
TC
    ${exists}    Exists    ./some_image.png
    Run Keyword If    "${exists}"=="true"    Run True Keyword
    ...    ELSE IF    "${exists}"=="false"   Run False Keyword
    ...    ELSE                              Run Error Keyword
```

This may be implemented as a seperate keyword which will click on the image if exists and otherwise ignores.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SikuliLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
TC
    # Check if button exist and retry for 2 seconds returning false.
    Click If Exists    ./ok_btn_dialog.png    ${2}
    Click             ./login_screen.png

*** Keywords ***
Click If Exists
    [Arguments]    ${image}    ${timeout}=${0}
    ${exists}    Exists    ${image}    ${timeout}
    Run Keyword If    "${exists}"=="true"    Click  ${image}
```

Comment: Will i use `ok_btn_dialog.png` instead of `some_image.png`, ? if ans is yes, so where i have use `Click` keyword for clicking on the `ok_btn_dialog.png`

Comment: Sorry, it does not for me :(, I have tried both the way, It executing the `Run Keyword If` keyword, but not detecting the image, going to next step

Comment: Added the timeout argument to the keyword. The sequence of steps may be too fast. So, add some wait time to allow for the OK button to appear.

Comment: Does it find the image when it is there or doesn't it?

Comment: It's always acting like there doesn't the image.

Comment: It's working fine now, the problem was in image, image outline was so thin, that is way unable to locate the image. Thanks for your effort :)